# How to get div data from html displayed after appending from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get data from the `var projectdata = localStorage.getItem('createProject')` from row highlighted . I have console log the `projectdata` as below with multiple records:

```css
.cleaner{float:left; padding:20px 10px 10px 20px;} 
.rows{width: 1000px; min-height: 80px;}
.rowsAlt{
background-color: #edece8;
}

.cols{height: 100%; float:left;}
.col1{width: 100px; float:left; padding:20px 10px 10px 20px;}
.col2{width: 100px; float:left; padding:20px 10px 10px 20px;}
.col3{width: 200px; float:left; padding:20px 10px 10px 20px;}
.col4{width: 150px; float:left; padding:20px 10px 10px 20px;}
.col5{width: 150px; float:left; padding:20px 10px 10px 20px;}
.col6{width: 100px; float:left; padding:20px 10px 10px 20px;}

#row2{
margin-left:20px; 
margin-top: 50px;
position: relative;
width: 90%;
margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.highlight { background: #ebdb34 !important; }
.projecteditLink{
height:10px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #42f56f;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"><div id="row2" class="rows rowsAlt"><div id="projectName_1" class="col1">Sun</div><div id="clientName_1" class="col2">sun</div><div class="col3">lion,wolves</div><div id="projectStartDate_1" class="col4">Nov-2019</div><div class="col5">Mr Rambo</div><div class="cleaner">Added Sun here</div><div class="col6"><a class="projecteditLink" href="">Edit Link</a></div></div></div><div class="row"><div id="row2" class="rows rowsAlt"><div id="projectName_2" class="col1">Moon Project</div><div id="clientName_2" class="col2">earth</div><div class="col3">lion,wolves</div><div id="projectStartDate_2" class="col4">Nov-2019</div><div class="col5">Mr Simmer</div><div class="cleaner">Added Sun here</div><div class="col6"><a class="projecteditLink" href="">Edit Link</a></div></div></div><div class="row"><div id="row2" class="rows rowsAlt"><div id="projectName_3" class="col1">Simple Demo</div><div id="clientName_3" class="col2">earth</div><div class="col3">man,lion</div><div id="projectStartDate_3" class="col4">Nov-2019</div><div class="col5">Mr Test</div><div class="cleaner">Added Simple here</div><div class="col6"><a class="projecteditLink" href="">Edit Link</a></div></div></div>
```

// Would like to get text like `Project One, SAAS, man`, from the variable `projectdata`. How to achieve that ?

```
   var divCount = 1;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('dashboardArea').innerHTML = "";
    var data = localStorage.getItem('saveToLocal');
    $('#dashboardArea').append(data);   
  $("body").on('click', '#saveProjecttoDash', function(e) {
    var projectdata = localStorage.getItem('createProject');
    console.log("Same here:"+projectdata);
    // How to get data from  `projectdata` html ?
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(300);
    var someDiv = '<div class="row"><div id="droppable'+divCount+'" class="pull-bottom" style="height:500px;background:#e3e8e7"><h3></h3><span class="clientNameDash"></span><img src="sampleImg.PNG" id="dashboardImage-"><img id="deleteDashboard" src="delete-512.png"></div></div>';
    $('#dashboardArea').append(someDiv);
    divCount++;
    var saveToLocalStorage = document.getElementById('dashboardArea').innerHTML;
    localStorage.setItem("saveToLocal",saveToLocalStorage);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to convert your string into an HTML object ( wrapped aroung a div )

```js
function createElementFromHTML (htmlString) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();
  return div;
}
```

And then pick out required values with `getElementsByClassName`

```js
const projectdata = localStorage.getItem('createProject');
const projectDataHTML = createElementFromHTML(projectdata);

const getInnerText= element => element.innerText;
const projectNames = [...projectDataHTML.getElementsByClassName('col1')].map(getInnerText); 
const clientNames = [...projectDataHTML.getElementsByClassName('col2')].map(getInnerText);
```

Result

```
projectNames ["Sun", "Moon Project", "Simple Demo"]
clientNames ["sun", "earth", "earth"]
```

Similarly you can pick out other values as well using their classNames (col3, col4...)

To get highlighted row record

```js
const [highlightedRow] = projectDataHTML.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
const highlightedProjectName = highlightedRow.getElementsByClassName("col1")[0].innerText;
const highlightedClientName = highlightedRow.getElementsByClassName("col2")[0].innerText;
```

Comment: One question, why do we need to convert to an HTML again. Also other problem is that, there are multiple records displayed inside overlay and each has different ID, so in that case how do we handle that here  `projectDataHTML.querySelector('#projectName_1').innerText;`

Comment: We convert to HTML object because it will be easier to get information in specific divs using `querySelector`. You can also use `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementById`. Can you update the question with the value of `projectdata` in case there are multiple records ?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question with necessary data/ multiple records.

Comment: @soccerway I have edited my answer to handle multiple records. Do have a look, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Abito, I have tried, now it always give me the text from first record and not from the highligted one.

Comment: @soccerway I have added additional code to get highlighted row record, this was not a part of the original question. Please upvote if answer this helped :) Happy coding.